# How to convert pyaudio frames into wav format without writing to a file?

Tags: python, audio, wav, pyaudio

I want to implement simple speech-to-text tool using pyaudio and IBM Bluemix service. Currently i need to record audio, save it to disk and then load again in order to send it to Bluemix.

```
RATE=44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
CHUNKSIZE = 1024

# initialize portaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE,     input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNKSIZE)

frames = [] # A python-list of chunks(numpy.ndarray)
print("Please speak!")

for _ in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNKSIZE * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    frames.append(np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.int16))

#Convert the list of numpy-arrays into a 1D array (column-wise)
numpydata = np.hstack(frames)

# close stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

# save audio to disk
wav.write('out.wav',RATE,numpydata)

# Open audio file(.wav) in wave format 
audio = open('/home/dolorousrtur/Documents/Projects/Capstone/out.wav', 'rb') 

# send audio to bluemix service
headers={'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'} 
r = requests.post(url, data=audio, headers=headers, auth=(username, password))
```

How can I convert pyaudio frames into wav format without writing them to disk?

Comment: I found code that does that. Class 'AudioData' frome here: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py has method get_wav_data() that returns object converted to wav format.

Comment: if the solution works could you please add it as a answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that worked for me. If you put the recorded audio into a `speech_recognition` `AudioData` object, there are methods available for converting to various audio formats (e.g., `get_wav_data()`, `get_aiff_data()`, `get_flac_data()`, etc.). See here: [speech_recognition AudioData](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/d7b26b45dcebe26dac1f5f518d4a352b56a67465/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L325)

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition
from time import sleep


class Recorder():

    sampling_rate = 44100
    num_channels = 2
    sample_width = 4 # The width of each sample in bytes. Each group of ``sample_width`` bytes represents a single audio sample. 

    def pyaudio_stream_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        self.raw_audio_bytes_array.extend(in_data)
        return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

    def start_recording(self):

        self.raw_audio_bytes_array = bytearray()

        pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.pyaudio_stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                      channels=self.num_channels,
                                      rate=self.sampling_rate,
                                      input=True,
                                      stream_callback=self.pyaudio_stream_callback)

        self.pyaudio_stream.start_stream()

    def stop_recording(self):

        self.pyaudio_stream.stop_stream()
        self.pyaudio_stream.close()

        speech_recognition_audio_data = speech_recognition.AudioData(self.raw_audio_bytes_array,
                                                                     self.sampling_rate,
                                                                     self.sample_width)
        return speech_recognition_audio_data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    recorder = Recorder()

    # start recording
    recorder.start_recording()

    # say something interesting...
    sleep(3)

    # stop recording
    speech_recognition_audio_data = recorder.stop_recording()

    # convert the audio represented by the ``AudioData`` object to
    # a byte string representing the contents of a WAV file
    wav_data = speech_recognition_audio_data.get_wav_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write to an in-memory file using a [BytesIO object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
import io

with io.BytesIO() as wav_file:
    wav_writer = wave.open(wav_file, "wb")
    try:
        wav_writer.setframerate(sample_rate)
        wav_writer.setsampwidth(sample_width)
        wav_writer.setnchannels(1)
        wav_writer.writeframes(raw_data)
        wav_data = wav_file.getvalue()
    finally:
        wav_writer.close()
```

Using @[Adrian Pope's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415410/34935), I got this code from speech_recognition, see [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/8b07762f80dfec2d34fb4c40b8eddbb7ec503521/speech_recognition/audio.py#L155).  That library has a [BSD license](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/LICENSE.txt), which permits re-use under certain conditions.

I have not tested this.